# Override form widget and/or Form for ManyToMany TabularInline

Tags: django, django-admin

Suppose I had two models as follows (example from [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models))

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name='groups')
```

And the following admin panel:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MembershipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Group.members.through

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MembershipInline,
    ]

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MembershipInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('members',)
```

Now, suppose that my database built up over the years, and I have lots and lots of `Person`s, but very little `Group`s. So for `Group`s, I can use the default widget, but I need a custom widget for `Person` inside `GroupAdmin`.

My question is, inside `MembershipInline`, how do I modify it so that the `Person`'s widget is overridden? I know this is possible with [`django-autocomplete-light`](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html) for `ForeignKey` `admin.TabularInline`s, but how do I modify this to come up with something for `ManyToMany` `admin.TabularInline`s? In other words, how do I modify the form going one way but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first need to separate out the `ManyToMany` table,

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group', through='Membership')

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Then I need to create the inline like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from .forms import *

class MembershipInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Membership
    form = MembershipForm

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MembershipInline,
    ]

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MembershipInline,
    ]
```

Then, in `forms.py`,

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class MembershipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        exclude = ()
        widgets = {
            'person': whatever_widget_i_want
        }
```

The `TabularInline` class will take care of removing the undesired field widget for me.